# Is it possible to scp/git push from my local machine to docker container hosted in AWS?

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, docker

Basically what it says in the question but my real purpose is to create a docker container in AWS to which I can push my code from git to do the deployment within the container.

So, let's say I have a docker image that has my environment all setup. It also has `bare` git repository which has `post-receive` hook that copies my file to specified dir within the container. That container has necessary ports exposed for me to access my app.

I have been successful on creating my image and setting it up in AWS but where I'm stuck is that I don't know how to connect my local machine to the container that's inside AWS.

I've tried port mapping while running like so:-

`docker run -d -i -p 80:3000 -p 8022:22 aws /bin/bash`
where `3000` is the port that I'm exposing from my container from my app and I was hoping to map ssh port of the container to some different port in my AWS instance (`8022`).

Still, no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated or if I'm going about this the wrong way then that'd be appreciated as well. I'm aware that this is a bit of overkill but I want this to be on EC2 (not Amazon's container service) only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your code in a volume bind-mounted to the host with `-v` and `rsync` it but the "proper" way is to bake a totally new Docker image and run that instead.

Comment: "but the "proper" way is to bake a totally new Docker image and run that instead."
I suppose I can do that since Docker cuts lot of overhead on downloading images.